# is it possible to only load part of a pickle file or can I use streaming?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I have a large pickle file which is a pandas dataframe. The data is minute data measuring certain weather metrics.

There are two operations that need to be run, on a daily basis which take longer than needed & I believe that is because of how I am loading the data.

```
# load the pickle file
with open('my_file.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    df = pd.read_pickle(handle)
```

So currently I load whole file just to get the last record in the dataframe which gives me the last time stamp of the last observation. Is there a way of loading part of the file?

Also once I have last time stamp, I then want to append the new data. Do I need to open the whole file & append the data to the dataframe or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Are you trying to select specific rows or columns from the pickled dataframe when reading it?

Comment: Do you really have to store the data as a pickle file? How about an SQL database (e. g. sqlite file) or a CSV-file?

Comment: Pickle is probably the wrong format for saving a dataframe, as well as for what you are trying to do. Can you change the format, use something else?

Comment: With an SQLite database, you can already preselect rows and columns beforehand, hence my first question?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a pickle file but sadly it can't be a SQL database due to the size limit of 10gb. The files are typically 1 to 2gb & we have multiple files

Comment: I'm just want to load the last row of the dataframe, I'm guessing when I save data I can store the last row somewhere else & read it instead of loading.